# How to use Pytorch and Huggingface to allocate GPU memory progressively

Tags: pytorch, gpu, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

My Pytorch code allocates the same amount of memory on each GPU. It does so even if it doesn't max out the device's memory. I can control the batch size per device which determines the memory/device allocated. But can I allocate the memory progressively, in order to first max out the first GPU, then the second, and so on...?

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]='1,2,3,4'

max_length = 64    
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=2).to("cuda")
train_encodings = tokenizer(train_texts, truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=max_length)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    per_device_train_batch_size=64,  # batch size per device during training
    ...
)

trainer = Trainer(
    args=training_args,              # training arguments, defined above
    ...
)
```